# Ayuda para obtener sesión de usuario en PHP?

Tags: php, session

Estoy practicando el tema de las sesiones en PHP pero aún no logro entender bien como funcionan.

Por ejemplo, tengo este problema básico donde deseo tomar la sesión de usuario que queda grabada cuando el mismo se registra:

Código:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

    unset($_SESSION['error']);

    if(!isset($_POST['usuario']) || !isset($_POST['contrasenia'])) {

    }else{

    $usuario     = $_POST["usuario"];
    $contrasenia = md5($_POST["contrasenia"]);

        if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from Usuarios where usuario='" . $usuario . "' and contrasenia='" . $contrasenia . "'")) {

            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

                if ($row['contrasenia'] == $contrasenia && $row['usuario'] == $usuario) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }
            } else {
                unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta";   
            }  
        }
    }
?>
```

Ver que si la sesión se inicia correctamente (osea, si el usuario existe) hago un session_start() y re-dirige al **index.php**.

Ahora en el index intento de tomar la sesion (veo en la consola del navegador que la sesion existe) pero el código no me anda:

Este es el código que tengo el en **index.php** :

```
  <?php

        if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
            session_start();
            $usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];
        } else{
            $usuario = "no user";
        }
?>
```

---- A esto le sigue mucho HTML y en algún lado dentro de este HTML imprimo el usuario  `<pre> <?php echo $usuario ?> </pre>` pero dentro de este pre me sale "no user" ... osea, la **$_SESSION["usuario"]** está vacia.

Que estoy haciendo mal ??

Alguna ayuda / consejo ??

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que **session_start();** debe de ir al principio para luego evaluarla, así:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    $usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];
  } else{
    $usuario = "no user";
  }

?>
```

**session_start();** siempre debe de ir primero antes de evaluar u obtener el valor de una sesión.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que iniciar la `session` antes de usar el `$_SESSION` en tu `index.php`

El código debería quedarse asi:

```
<?php
session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){ 
            $usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];
        } else{
            $usuario = "no user";
        }
?>
```